# Can range(len()) be evaluated multiple times within a for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Within a while-loop the condition get's iteratively re-evaluated. Example:

```
while i < len(nums):
```

Both the latest index `i` and the latest length of `nums` are used to re-evaluate the condition.

This is not the case within a for-loop. Example:

```
for i in range(len(nums)):
```

Here `range(len(nums))` is created and remains unchanged even when the length of `nums` changes (e.g., due to popping values within the loop). Is my understanding of this process correct? Is there a way to make the for-loop dependent on 'a moving goal post' (the changing `nums` length)?

Comment: No, modifying a container whilst looping is asking for trouble.

Comment: You never need it.

Comment: You can create a generator, which will dynamically yield a value on each iteration; the generator could therefore check the `len` before each iteration of the loop.  That said, it remains a terrible idea to modify a container that you're iterating over, whether you're using `for` or `while` or a custom generator to accomplish the actual iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is not the case within a for-loop

No. This is the case when you create a `range` object. `range` does not store a reference to `nums` it just takes the integer. If you had a list

```
ls = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Then you could write:

```
for i in ls:
    ls.append(i)
```

and the loop would run forever, because you are getting `i` from `ls` and `ls` is being added to each time. I would not recommend trying to use this to achieve your goal, though. Using a while loop makes sense here.

Comment: But what if you need the index? I have a list of all possible options and have to check some conditions to see which are valid and i'm using `del` so i don't have to loop again and make another list, but it doesn't work with the usual pythonic `for`. Can you just not do it with a for in that case?

Comment: @Konstei I suggest posting this as a question on its own, with a [mre] available.

Answer (score 2):

You could use enumerate(nums) to iterate through the list getting the current index and still go further if the list gets longer.

In the following example i used random to have a chance of applying a new item with every iteration.

```
>>> import random
>>>
>>> nums = ["a", "a"]
>>>
>>> for i, val in enumerate(nums):
...    if random.randint(0, 1)==0:
...       nums.append("b")
...    print(str(i)+":"+val)
...
0:a
1:a
2:b
3:b
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a generator that simply hides a `while` loop.

```
def range_len(lst):
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        yield i
        i += 1

for i in range_len(nums):
    ...
```

This is pointless except to demonstrate that a `for` loop can iterate over a changing iterable. It works because the `lst` within the generator is the same object as `nums` and so its length will be re-evaluated on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a necessary reason to use for and not while then here are some ideas:

If the intent is to avoid running out of list boundaries as a result of the list shrinking at runtime (I have not tested this), then I would put a condition at that critical part of the body to reassess i against len(n) and break accordingly.

If the intent is to continue with the for loop in case the length expands, then maybe I would consider nested loops with the outer being while True with a breaking condition (if i reaches len(n)). In that case the starting value of the inner loop will not always be zero.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a variable and set the length of the array for each loop

```
 nums = [1, 2 ,3 ,4]
 i=0
 array_length=len(nums)
 while i < array_length:
   nums.pop()
   print(nums)
   array_length=len(nums)
```

Comment: that is good for a while, but does not answer the question about for + range -> there it does not work. the range is checked once on start!